Identifying points on the hypersphere with points on the trace of a real projective geodesic
Let $\boldsymbol u^{(1)},\dots,\boldsymbol u^{(T)} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ live in the intersection of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ with some $2$-dimensional linear subspace $\mathscr{U}$:  $$\{ \boldsymbol  u^{(i)} \}_{i=1}^{T} \subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1} \cap \mathscr{U}.$$ In other words, the $\boldsymbol u^{(i)}$ belong to a great circle arc on the $(d-1)$-sphere.
Does the set $\{\text{span}(\boldsymbol u_{}^{(1)}), \text{span}(\boldsymbol u_{}^{(2)}),\dots, \text{span}(\boldsymbol u_{}^{(T)})\}$ live in the trace of a geodesic on the real projective space $\text{Gr}(1,d)$? If not, do there exist additional hypotheses under which it would?

The wedge product of any of the two said eigenvectors should give 22-forms that are proportional to one-another. The resulting 22-forms represents in an abstract sense the 22-plane in which the operand vectors are located. Alternatively, the wedge product of any 33 of the eigenvectors should vanish. This is equivalent to saying the 3 are coplanar.

hi there, thanks for your comment. would it be possible to elaborate on where 22-forms are coming from? I don't have much of a differential geometry background, but my recollection is that the wedge product of two vectors is a 2-form.

Sorry, I meant $2$-forms and $3$-forms. I don't know how that typo got in. It seems I wrote 33 instead of $3$ and 22 instead of $2$.

I'm confused. Isn't the hypothesis given sufficient? The hypothesis says that the $u_1^{(i)}$ lie on a great circle of $\mathbb{S}^{d - 1}$ (assuming the $2$-plane $\mathcal{U}$ contains the origin), which is a geodesic of $\mathbb{S}^{d - 1}$. So their spans should lie on a geodesic of real projective space.

I think my concern might boil down to what definition of geodesic is involved. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200859/geodesic-in-metric-space-and-in-manifolds (perhaps the hypothesis given suffices for the second definition provided in that link)
