# Definition of geodesic in metric spaces

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

My question is closely related to this:

[On the definition of a geodesic in a metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614439/on-the-definition-of-a-geodesic-in-a-metric-space)

I don't understand why in the definition of the geodesic there is the requirement of *constant speed*. As far as I understand, the *constant speed* is given by a particular parametrization. However, the length is independent of the parametrization. Intuitively, the concept of a geodesic is related to the length of the path, so it should be independent of the parametrization as well. Why isn't the following a good definition of a geodesic:

A path $\gamma: I\to X$ is a geodesic, if for any $t\in I$, there exists a nbhd $U$ of $t$ such that for any $t_1, t_2\in U$ one has
$$
d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))=L(\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]})
$$

where $L(\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]})$ is the length of the path $\gamma$ restricted to $[t_1,t_2]$.

This definition includes the constant speed geodesic, but not only. There is something I misunderstand, what am I missing here?

Comment: What is your background? Are you familiar with Riemannian geometry and it's notion of geodesics?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I am not familiar with Riemann geometry. I have a naive intuition of a geodesic between two points being the shortest path. That's where I am probably wrong.

Comment: In Riemannian (and semi-Riemannian) geometry geodesics are defined as curves with zero acceleration, which implies constant speed. As it turns out, Riemannian geodesics are also distance-minimizers. The definition of geodesics in metric spaces is chosen to be as close to the Riemannian one as possible.

Comment: I see. For example, I am not entirely correct when I say that the "geodesic" between two points on the sphere is the shortest arc on a big circle. The "geodesic" is a constant speed parameterization of the arc, and not the arc itself. Not any parametrization that has the arc as its image is a geodesic. Probably doesn't make much difference: if there exist a distance minimizer path then there exist a constant speed distance minimizer path. Am I on the right path (no pun intended)?

Comment: I think the idea is that, if you don't include this condition, you will need another condition stating that the velocity never can be zero, so you might as well pick unit length parametrisation to start with.

Comment: In the theory of metric spaces different authors use slightly different conventions regarding geodesics. Some require geodesics to be only locally minimizing, while some conflate geodesics and their images, others define geodesics as isometric embeddings of intervals to the metric space, etc. This depends on personal preferences of authors, traditions in the given subfield of metric geometry, etc. Yes, if there is a distance-minimizing path, there is also one with constant speed (and the same image).